# angular universal configuration with webpack starter project

Tags: angular

I am trying to following the configuration for angular universal as per angular website - https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/

I have already done first 2 steps on this document i.e. to use angular webpack-starter project and then i have written my code in this project. 
The 3rd step is to configure this project for universal. This does not work as given on the website. I think there are some mistakes in the 3rd steps but not sure what should be the correct code for server.ts and how to start the server so that angular universal works. Any input on this will be a great help.

I am using angular 2 rc 4.

Comment: Which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I am using Angular 2 rc 4.

Comment: If you want a friendly advice, just stop wasting your time trying to make that work. Wait until angular universal supports RC5 or RC6 and them migrate your app to RC5/6

Comment: @FabioAntunes this is not rc4 issue. there are other projects using rc 4 and universal is working for them. I think the issue here is my lack of understanding of webpack configuration. I do not know exactly what is going wrong in webpack configuration in this seed project.

Comment: I know it's not an rc4 issue, but rc5 has some breaking changes. And universal doesn't work with the new router yet